# How to merge mp4 videos using R

Tags: r

I have several mp4 videos (with audio). I want to merge these so that I have a single video file. I can do this on the desktop, e.g. using QuickTime 7 Pro on the Mac. But I need an automated cloud-based solution, preferably using R. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Look at the [av](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/av/av.pdf) package and specifically the `av_video_convert()` function.

Comment: Thank you @caldwellst. I used the following command to concatenate 3 videos in a folder called "www":

files <- sprintf("www/video_%d.mp4", 1:3)

av_video_convert(files, output = "test.mp4")

All have audios. But what happens is that the audio of the first video is maintained but the rest of the audio is not. So all but the first video have no audio on the final result.

Comment: Hi @Kaveh1000. Not a specialist, but maybe you can try the `av_encode_video()` function from the same package. Cheers.